# Error: Cannot load preset env relative to / in a browser

Tags: javascript, babel-preset-env, babel-core

I am creating interactive JavaScript coding exercise using [ACE](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor) editor. 
to execute entered code have have to transform code. for that i am using `@balel/core transform` method. I am facing below problems

1. when I use  `presets: ["env"]` in options i am getting `Error: Cannot load preset env relative to / in a browser`.
   I already did `npm install babel-preset-env` to install preset
2. `transform` is not overriding option `babelrc: true`

Answer (score 1):

cannot run babe-core in browser begin with version 6.0. only node
so you can refer to babel-standalone.
https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone