# Typescript to Javascript convert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I was wondering if it is possible to utilise `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` to translate typescript code to javascript code when the function is called during user interaction, for example, when the user clicks on a button. My goal is to show the source code on the page as you can see below. So far I managed to put it only in typescript; however, I want to also be able to view it in JS[image: l]

The code that I have right now: [image]

The problem is that I get this error when I click on the button that triggers the function: [image]

Do you have any suggestion how to resolve this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typescript already compiles into JavaScript. So maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, but you shouldn't need any other package, it does that on its own.

Comment: I know it does compile it to Javascript; however, my goal is to show the source code on my page. The thing is I want it to be also in Javascript so I am looking for a solution. @TaylorBurke

Comment: You can compile your code to JavaScript using the typescript compiler. See specification here. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Looking at [this question with a title similar to your  error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53427901/215552) it seems you need to use [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html)...